# Create subclasses of parent class from file

Tags: java, constructor

I'm trying to create a menu screen, and I want to be able to create it, and any further permutations of it dynamically. I've created a MenuItem helper class to handle the menu items that show up, and it reads the name, image, and set the next state (something that is handled later). What I want to know is, how can I create the specific following Screens (they'll all be some subclass of my Screen class)?

What is the most efficient method to pass specific objects into the menuItems? Do I need to pre-create each possible Screen and then just read back in the serialized form of it, or can I create them dynamically. I'd hoped to be able to do something as simple as reading in a literal string "new SubClass(...)" and act off that, but I don't know how to go about that. Any other suggestions would be great!

Comment: Try posting some code (better even posting an SSCCE http://sscce.org) or at least some pseudo-code because I can't understand a thing from what you're saying.

Comment: Can you post your Screen Class code?

Comment: What kind of app are you developing? AWT application? Swing? Webapp?

Comment: Designing a menu driven UI is a well-explored task. you should be able to google a dozen menu frameworks depending on your hw platform and application requirements. For example - http://code.google.com/p/menudesigner/

Comment: AWT already support menus and menu items. The corresponding classes are java.awt.Menu and java.awt.MenuItem. You tell them what to do when clicked by adding an ActionListener, which will be called when the menu item is selected.

Comment: @JBNizet It is an AWT application. 

The Screen class itself is rather mundane. It's an abstract class with a basic doubleBuffer(), addBackground(), addForeground(), etc, etc. The question is in the Menu() subclass of the Screen.

The thing I need to do is that each MenuItem (except exit) will lead to another Screen specific Screen subclass. I just want to be able to read that in from a .txt file at run-time. For Example:

BufferedReader in = ...;
String read;
...
while(read = in.readLine())
{
 //read name, img, etc
 
 //create new Screen subclass as MenuItems' nextScreen class
}

Comment: @JBNizet I'm not talking about the top menu, this is all done on Canvas, so by menu, I mean one full screen, there is no top bar menu like in a conventional desktop application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want is a mechanism that reads a String command from a text file, and based on this command, displays a screen.

So, extract the interface of the "display screen" command into an interface. For example:

```
public interface ScreenDisplayer {
    void displayScreen(Screen mainScreen);
}
```

Then build a `Map<String, ScreenDisplayer>`:

```
map.put("screen1", new ScreenDisplayer() {
    @Override
    void displayScreen(Screen mainScreen) {
        // TODO display screen 1
    });
// same for all the other commands
```

And when a "menu item" is clicked, get the DisplayScreen from the map and call it:

```
String command = selectedMenuItem.getCommand();
ScreenDisplayer displayer = map.get(command);
displayer.displayScreen(mainScreen);
```

Comment: Basically, I'm just wondering, at that point, how do I specify each command? All I'm looking to do is specific which subclass constructor, and give it's arguments dynamically (preferably from String).

<pre>
new,./CatchEm/imgs/new.png,new constructor,1
load,./CatchEm/imgs/load.png,load constructor,1
options,./CatchEm/imgs/options.png,options constructor,1
exit,./CatchEm/imgs/exit.png,null,0
</pre>
would be an example text file I read in, with the comma as the separator

Comment: On second inspection, I am definitely over-complicating the problem. What I'm looking for can basically be summed up into 7 or 8 commands. So perhaps an enum containing the ScreenDisplayers or just a second helper class to contain them all? Or, no you're right, a Map works just fine